# How do I change 'example.com' in my code?

Tags: python, django

I built a `a.py` in my mysite file,

a.py:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from mysite import settings

setup_environ(settings)

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
print domain
```

It prints:

> :example.com

How do I change the 'domain' to 127.0.0.1:8000?

---

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from register import settings
setup_environ(settings)


from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
#domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
#print domain

from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
obj=Site.objects.get(id=1).update(name='sss')
print obj
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\register\a.py", line 13, in <module>
    obj=Site.objects.get(id=1).update(name='sss')
AttributeError: 'Site' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like whrd commented, you can't call `update(...)` on the result of calling `get(...)` on a `QuerySet`. A better way of changing your code is as follows:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from register import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

obj=Site.objects.get(id=1)
obj.name='sss'
obj.save()
print obj
```

Answer (score 8):

Go to the `Site` model in the admin interface and change the value there. Or do a query on Site at the Django prompt and modify and save the model.

Comment: hi Ignacio,see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107456/how-do-i-change-example-com-in-my-code/2107649#2107649

Answer (score 4):

Put a file call initial_data.json in your project directory with the following content :
`[{
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "sites.site",
        "fields": {
            "name": "localhost:8080",
            "domain":"localhost:8080"
        }
    }
]`
then use python manage.py syncdb et voilà the settings are changed.